# How can I access menu bar items alike hud (unity)?

Tags: arch-linux, unity, dmenu

Currently I have archlinux installed, but I used Ubuntu in the past.

What I really miss from ubuntu is the HUD from unity which allows hotkey searching for top menu bar items from the current application, without the need for using the mouse or using shortcuts, kind of dmenu:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-unitys-hud-feature-in-ubuntu-12-04

There is a repository for unity in archlinux, but is too cumbersome, especially since I only want the HUD.

Is there other alternatives out there that I could use?

Or any way through coding to access menu bar items information?

Answer (score 1):

DMenu can't access an application's menu, which is needed for the HUD function. If you use KDE, there's `kdeplasma-runners-appmenu-git` in AUR, but aside from that, the feature seems to be unique to Unity so far.